# GPS data to a website

Tags: asp.net, gps

There is a GPS device which can send data to IP:Port. I have a website hosted on IP 1.2.3.4
Can I send GPS data from the device to that website? 1.2.3.4:8080? How I will retrieve the data?

This is the device
http://cgi.ebay.com/GSM-GPRS-GPS-Vehicle-Car-Tracking-System-Tracker-Device-/270683202099?pt=AU_Car_Parts_Accessories&hash=item3f05f9e233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this should be a comment...

To be honest we can't answer that question the device will most likely use its own data format(s) so the service that receives from it will have to implement those.  Additionally the device might not support web protocols, it could use raw TCP sockets for example, so you may have to implement a listener service that adheres to those protocols.  In fact it looks like the device uses GSM (a mobile telephony standard), so using a web site to receive the data is definately off the cards unless you have a GSM proxy service sitting between the device and the web server.

Assuming that you are allowed to implement your own service it follows that the documentation will include the necessary details and if you are lucky a full SDK that you can use.